# Изменить размер дисплея linux

Tags: linux

Возможно ли изменить размер дисплея (разрешение) nongui оболочки linux запущенного на виртуальной машине?

Comment: Во-первых, что такое «nongui оболочка»? Во-вторых, ну смотрите настройки видео в настройках вашей виртуальной машины, наверное?

Comment: я имею ввиду linux без графической оболочки, в настройках VBox кроме масштабирования ничего нет

Comment: Попробуйте поменять используя `xrandr` (прм. `xrandr --size ШИРИНАxВЫСОТА`)

Comment: Xrandr это с оболочкой

Comment: Нашел ответ на зарубежном стаке
https://superuser.com/questions/816528/with-centos-7-as-a-virtualbox-guest-on-a-mac-host-how-can-i-change-the-screen-r

Answer (score 0):

fbset для настройки фреймбуфера

Comment: Не факт что фреймбуфер вообще есть

Comment: Судя по комменту vbox - фреймбуфер есть

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял - у вас там "безголовый" хост. То есть без графики, голая консоль. Ну так тогда вам "мониторы" все эти и не нужны. Просто ходите внутрь хоста об ssh. Установите на своей машине условный putty (ну или WLS2 + windows terminal и уже там ssh), и привыкайте к хорошему :)